# p tag is not expanding its width when a fixed height is given to p in a flexbox container

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow, word-break

Here is an example (with codepen included)

https://codepen.io/Sanjid-Chowdhury/pen/QWBBGbJ

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

p {
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Your data</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam nesciunt quam et repellendus harum possimus sequi, iusto nam tempore qui, sit quasi! Velit nisi numquam, non accusamus atque perspiciatis aperiam?</p>
  <p>WAFIjwaf oakd owad kalwd koawd sla ksa olafwa kosad </p>
  <p>afwad op wafk ag jasglksakmdfgfi efkf aioefjw oafkw alfk awijf jf dasklfskjasf ds</p>
  <p>eafifa osd okasg oeoagkesfal s;sdfpoasef ksadlf eaigjwg</p>
</div>
```

If you decrease the window size, you will see that the `<p>` tag overflows vertically. I am looking for a behavior where the `<p>` tag will expand just as much as it needs to, given its fixed height. If i set the width of the `.container` to `width: max-content`, the whole tag turns into a line of text. I want it to take the available fixed height and then expand its width if the text starts to overflow vertically.

Comment: you cannot do this with CSS

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I have searched the web for a solution or explanation but couldn't find any. And can you also give any alternatives?

Answer (score -2):

Try to add `white-space:nowrap` to your `p` tag

```css
.container {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
}

p {
  height: 40px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Your data</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam nesciunt quam et repellendus harum possimus sequi, iusto nam tempore qui, sit quasi! Velit nisi numquam, non accusamus atque perspiciatis aperiam?</p>
  <p>WAFIjwaf oakd owad kalwd koawd sla ksa olafwa kosad </p>
  <p>afwad op wafk ag jasglksakmdfgfi efkf aioefjw oafkw alfk awijf jf dasklfskjasf ds</p>
  <p>eafifa osd okasg oeoagkesfal s;sdfpoasef ksadlf eaigjwg</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, not the answer I was looking for. I want the p tag to not overflow vertically but also want it to fill up vertically before expanding its width

Comment: hi you need to remove height for p tags and try to make space ( if you want ) with padding or line-height